# overloading >= operator to compare pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload `>=` operator to Point class, so that I could compare two pointers to Point instances. But it does not look it calls the overloaded operator at all, because it is not printing the debug output.
Why the overloaded operator is not called? How to make it work?

The code I am trying is in file `operator.cc`:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

class Point {
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x, int y);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    bool operator>=(Point* p);
};

Point::Point(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x; this->y = y;
}

int Point::getX() {
    return this->x;
}
int Point::getY() {
    return this->y;
}

bool Point::operator>=(Point* p) {
    std::cout << "overloaded>=" << std::endl; // does not print anything
    return this->x >= p->getX() && this->y >= p->getY();
}

int main() {
    Point* p1 = new Point(5, 5);
    Point* p2 = new Point(4, 4);
    bool result = p1 >= p2;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile and run this code with `g++ operator.cc -o op && ./op`, then I always get output `false`, and it doesn't print the `overloaded>=` debug message.

Comment: Your overload is between `Point` and `Point*`, not two pointers, the latter of which cannot be overloaded. Why not `(*p1) >= (*p2)`? Also why are you using `new` at all in this context?

Comment: You are getting false as you are comparing pointers. Change comparison to *p1 >= *p2, change the function to bool Point::operator>=(const Point& p) and body of the function appropriately.

Comment: Your operator would be invoked by `(*p1) >= p2`

Comment: Advice -- overload `<` and `==` instead of `>=`.  All other operators can be created from those two operators, plus your class becomes instantly more robust.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, what do you need `==` for ?  It can be created from `<`.

Comment: @SidS: If you use `std::find` (for one example) that uses `==` (since it can be used on items that define equality but not ordering). You can synthesize `==` from `<`, but it doesn't happen on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost always want to compare actual `Point` objects, not a pointer to a `Point`.

```
bool Point::operator>=(Point const & p) {
    std::cout << "overloaded>=\n"; // should now print something
    return x >= p.x && y >= p.y;
}
```

Then you'd invoke it like:

```
int main() {
    Point p1{5, 5};
    Point p2{4, 4};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p1>=p2) << '\n';
}
```

As a side note, if you support comparison in C++, it's (much) more common to overload `operator<` instead. By default standard algorithms will compare for less than, rather than greater than/equal to.

But, if you do decide to implement `operator<` for use with standard algorithms, you'll have to ensure that it carries out a "strict weak" comparison, which your current comparison is not (as it stands now, there are values of A and B (e.g., {4,5} and {5,4}) for with both A>=B and B>=A will return false, indicating that A is neither less than, nor equal to, nor greater than B. A comparison operator like that can (and often will) produce undefined behavior from things like sorting algorithms.

Comment: As a side side note, this is not a valid comparison operator for standard algorithms, because `Point(5,4) >= Point(4,5)` is false and `Point(4,5) >= Point(5,4)` is also false. Apparently these two points are neither greater than, less than or equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a member function of a class from a pointer to an object, the following approach is used.
Suppose there is another function in class Point named cmp which takes a pointer as an argument.

```
bool Point::cmp(Point *p)
{
return true;
}
```

It can be invoked by pointer p1 by `(*p1).cmp(p2)`.

Similarly, the overloaded operator >= can also be invoked via:

```
bool result = *p1 >= p2;
```